# Não ocorre leitura do arquivo csv no d3

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

Eu estou tentando fazer um arquivo .md que abriga três visualizações. Sendo que, quando chega na segunda visualização(grafico) dá o erro abaixo no console do browser.

[image: Erro no console do browser]

Eu estou tentando carregar um arquivo csv que está na mesma pasta do script 
em js que o chama.

```
d3.csv("data3.csv", function(data){
...
});
```

'data' é dada como variável nula.
Como faça para resolver o erro do console.

Comment: Qual é a versão do `D3` que esta a utilizar ?

Comment: Estou usando a versão 4.

Comment: Poderia criar um [mcve], pois apenas com essa parte do código fica impossível localizar o problema. Coloque o código do arquivo **freqMulheres.js**